# How to select which relics to retain vs to salvage in the junk pile

Tags: clicker-heroes

I'm a little confused about what I should or should not retain in the way of relics. Does anyone have a rule of thumb for this?

I'm forced to decide so as to allow me to ascend. This is a bit odd because each world has one relic, so every ascension you can have 4 saved relics and 1 in the junk pile at most. It is not really a pile. I don't know why the interface's box is so large.

To illustrate with my specific case I have (direct transcription sorry for the obvious text and lack of abbreviations):

1. Ranger Gloves of Diseases Rare Level 23

   - -3% Boss Life
   - +0.5% Chance of 10x Gold
   - +2% Chance of Primal Bosses
2. Copper Mark of Wrath Common Level 34

   - +140% Click Damage
   - +249% Gold gained from monsters when idle (no clicks for 60 seconds)
   - +3% Chance of double rubies from clickable treasures, when you get a ruby.
3. Copper Band of Souls Common Level 26

   - +3% Chance of Primal Bosses
   - +4 seconds to duration of Lucky Strikes
4. Ranger Gloves of Greed Uncommon Level 35

   - +175% Gold Dropped
5. Rusty Sword of Battery Life Common Level 22

   - +17 seconds to duration of Metal Detector
   - +2 to starting zone after Ascension
   - +50% Gold gained from monsters when idle (no clicks for 60 seconds)
   - +1 seconds to duration of Clickstorm

Going on rarity I might get rid of the lowest level common item (#5) or going on level I might get rid of the lowest level item (also #5). However I *am* and idle style player and I am not sure I want to give up the +50% Gold when idle compared to giving up say (#1) the -3% Boss Life, +0.5% Chance of 10x Gold, +2% Chance of Primal Bosses. I mean I like primal bosses having a better chance, and the 10x gold thing is awesome when it happens to a treasure chest... but really, over all +50% gold might progress faster & further? It's hard for me to say.

Comment: the box is large because you can buy packs of extra relics via rubies (currently 3 per 40), which on very deep (long between resets) runs you will end up with many rubies, and chances at more than the 1 relic that run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit subjective due to play style; but all 4 of my relics either have the % Chance of Primal Bosses or & Primal Souls.

Also keep in mind that these bonuses are all additive.

Per the [relics wiki page](http://clickerheroes.wikia.com/wiki/Relics); they've broken it down into tiers (although this is also probably subjective as well).

Top tier is `+ % Chance of Primal Bosses`

Middle tier consists of:

```
- % Hero Hiring and Level-Up cost
+ % chance of double rubies
+ Duration (lucky strikes being best)
+ % Primal Hero Souls
+ % 10x gold
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your play style. If you are an idle person keep the relics that upgrade siyalatas and libertas. If you are the active person keep the ones that upgrade Juggernaut and fragsworth. If you are farming hero souls keep the relics that upgrade solomon. If your a boss farmer keep the ones that upgrade chronos and bubos. If you are farming gold keep the ones that upgrade mammon and/or libertas. Thanks for taking your time to read my comment.